# Android Studio Emulator crashing when trying to run multi-class project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have a multi class project. This is the assignment: Create an app that allows to enter information to order package delivery.  I have to have the two additional classes, and pass the information from one to the other, but I'm not sure why the app is wanting to crash to even see if the code will work.  My instructor has looked at it without much luck, but he's so busy I decided to see if others could take a peek at it. Thanks in advance!

The **MainActivity.Java**

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    parcel parcelObject;
    address addressObject;
    EditText startAdd;
    EditText startZip;
    EditText endAdd;
    EditText endZip;
    EditText parcelWeight;
    Button button;
    TextView textView;






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        //addressObject = new address(this);
        parcelObject = new parcel(this);



    }
    public void buttonOnClick(View v ) {
        Button button=(Button) v;
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.shippingTotal);
        parcelObject.shipping();
        textView.setText("Your Shipping Total is: $ " + parcelObject.sCost);
    }
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**address.java**

```js
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


/**
 * Created by Cyn on 10/16/2015.
 */
public class address {
    parcel parcelObject;
    EditText startAdd;
    EditText startZip;
    EditText endAdd;
    EditText endZip;


    double sZip, eZip;

    public  address (Activity activity) {
       startAdd = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.originZip);
        startZip = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.originZip);
        endAdd = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.destAdd);
        endZip = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.destZip);


        sZip = Double.parseDouble(startZip.getText().toString());
        eZip = Double.parseDouble(endAdd.getText().toString());
    }




}
```

and the **parcel.java**

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Cyn on 10/16/2015.
 */
public class parcel {
    address addressObject;
    EditText startAdd;
    EditText startZip;
    EditText endAdd;
    EditText endZip;
    EditText parcelWeight;

    double sZip, eZip, pWeight, sCost;

    public parcel(Activity activity) {
        addressObject = new address(activity);
        startAdd = addressObject.startAdd;
       endAdd = addressObject.endAdd;
        endZip = addressObject.endZip;
        sZip = addressObject.sZip;
        eZip = addressObject.eZip;

        parcelWeight = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.packageWeight);
        pWeight = Double.parseDouble(parcelWeight.getText().toString());


    }

    public void shipping() {

        if (sZip == eZip) {
            sCost = pWeight * 1;
        } else {
            sCost = pWeight * 2;
        }

    }
}
```

And the where the error parts of the android monitor are:

```js
11-20 01:27:53.768 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime: Process: cyn.assignment4, PID: 1444
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cyn.assignment4/cyn.assignment4.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at cyn.assignment4.address.<init>(address.java:33)
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at cyn.assignment4.parcel.<init>(parcel.java:22)
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at cyn.assignment4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
11-20 01:27:53.772 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
11-20 01:28:36.701 1444-1451/cyn.assignment4 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 135.053ms
11-20 01:30:38.025 1444-1451/cyn.assignment4 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 218.758ms
11-20 01:31:17.505 1444-1444/cyn.assignment4 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1444 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I recommend that you learn how to read error messages. The problem is written right there: *Invalid double: ""* on the constructor of your `Address` class on line 33. If you go there, the problem is clearly with the Double conversion when you call `Double.parseDouble()`.

Comment: Ricardo is right. The mistake is to call `Double.parseDouble` with an empty string argument. The mistake seems to be that you are creating an object too early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the answers were partially right, two small changes made the code work. One being a simple typo fix (that I didn't catch).

First, a change in the main activity: Where we moved the "parcelObject = new parcel (this);   from the onCreate, to the top of the buttonOnClick

```js
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        //addressObject = new address(this);
        



    }
    public void buttonOnClick(View v ) {
        parcelObject = new parcel(this);
        Button button=(Button) v;
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.shippingTotal);
        parcelObject.shipping();
        textView.setText("Your Shipping Total is: $ " + parcelObject.sCost);
    }
```

Then the small typo was with:

```js
sZip = Double.parseDouble(startZip.getText().toString());
eZip = Double.parseDouble(endAdd.getText().toString())
```

it should be:

```js
sZip = Double.parseDouble(startZip.getText().toString());
eZip = Double.parseDouble(endZip.getText().toString())
```

"endAdd" verse "endZip" , what must have happened was that I probably clicked the wrong auto fill.

but to snazz up the code a bit more , this is the final address.java code:

```js
package cyn.assignment4;

import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


/**
 * Created by Cyn on 10/16/2015.
 */
public class address {
    parcel parcelObject;
    EditText startAdd;
    EditText startZip;
    EditText endAdd;
    EditText endZip;


    double sZip, eZip;

    public  address (Activity activity) {
       startAdd = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.originZip);
        startZip = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.originZip);
        endAdd = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.destAdd);
        endZip = (EditText)activity.findViewById(R.id.destZip);

        String checkUserInput =  startZip.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(checkUserInput)) {
            startZip.setError("You must enter a valid zip code");
        }
        else {
            sZip = Double.parseDouble(startZip.getText().toString());

        }

        String checkUserInput2 =  endZip.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(checkUserInput2)) {
            endZip.setError("You must enter a valid zip code!");
        }
        else {
            eZip = Double.parseDouble(endZip.getText().toString());
        }

    }
```

So that with the small movement chance in the main activity and the app works like a charm :).

Answer (score 0):

```
sZip = Double.parseDouble(startZip.getText().toString());
eZip = Double.parseDouble(endAdd.getText().toString());
```

Here is it. You are trying to parse `double` from a `String`, and the `String` is empty. Check it first with

```
if(!startZip.getText().toString().isEmpty&& startZip.getText()!=null){
    sZip = Double.parseDouble(startZip.getText().toString());
}
if(!endAdd.getText().toString().isEmpty&&endAdd.getText()!=null)...
```